# How to upload file in angular 2

Tags: angular2-forms

This is the function I am using to upload file but is is giving me the error : Length is undefined. what I have to change in this code. where to give path of file to upload.

```
fileChange(event) {
        let fileList: FileList = event.target.files;
        if(fileList) {
            let file: File = fileList[0];
            let formData:FormData = new FormData();
            formData.append('uploadFile', file, file.name);
            let headers = new Headers();
            /** No need to include Content-Type in Angular 4 */
            headers.append('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
            headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
            let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
            this.http.post(`assets/Files/info.txt`, formData, options)
                .map(res => res.json())
                .catch(error => Observable.throw(error))
                .subscribe(
                    data => console.log(fileList),
                    error => console.log(error)
                )
             }
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use xhr request to transfer files

```
fileChange(event: EventTarget) {
    let eventObj: MSInputMethodContext = <MSInputMethodContext> event;
    let target: HTMLInputElement = <HTMLInputElement> eventObj.target;
    let files: FileList = target.files;
    if(files) {
        let file: File = files[0];
        this.upload(file) 
      }
}
public upload(filedata: File) {
    let url = 'your url'
    if (typeof filedata != 'undefined') {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let formData: any = new FormData();
            let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            formData.append('icondata', filedata, filedata.name);
            xhr.open('POST', url, true);
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'JWT ' + localStorage.getItem('id_token'));
            xhr.send(formData);
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
                    resolve(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: How do i use it in html. <input type="file">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" id ="uploadFile">
        Update File
        </button>   On (change) event it is not working.

Comment: <input name="filename" id="imagefileId" type="file" (change)="fileChange($event)">

Comment: I go this error SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Comment: can check your backend ,your backend response is wrong

Comment: Actually i have no backend I am using it on local. I have to upload file on click of button.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that this is not the functionality you want to have but with no backend you can not upload files to be persistent, they should be stored somewhere. If you just wanna manipulate file names for instance, skip the express part in my answer. I personally used this code which I altered to upload multiple files.

In your **Component** :

```
import {FormArray, FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup} from "@angular/forms";
```

declare FormBuilder in the constructor:

```
constructor (private http: Http, private fb: FormBuilder) {}
```

in `ngOnInit()` set a variable as follows :

```
this.myForm = this.fb.group({chosenfiles: this.fb.array([])});
```

this is the code for the upload method :

```
// invoke the upload to server method
// TODO
// Should be in a service (injectable)
    upload() {
        const formData: any = new FormData();
        const files: Array<File> = this.filesToUpload;
        //console.log(files);
        const chosenf = <FormArray> this.myForm.controls["chosenfiles"];
        // iterate over the number of files
        for(let i =0; i < files.length; i++){
            formData.append("uploads[]", files[i], files[i]['name']);
            // store file name in an array
            chosenf.push(new FormControl(files[i]['name']));
        }
        this.http.post('http://localhost:3003/api/upload', formData)
            .map(files => files.json())
            .subscribe(files => console.log('upload completed, files are : ', files));
    }
```

the method responsible for the file change :

```
fileChangeEvent(fileInput: any) {
    this.filesToUpload = <Array<File>>fileInput.target.files;
    const formData: any = new FormData();
    const files: Array<File> = this.filesToUpload;
    console.log(files);
    const chosenf = <FormArray> this.myForm.controls["chosenfiles"];
    // iterate over the number of files
    for(let i =0; i < files.length; i++){
        formData.append("uploads[]", files[i], files[i]['name']);
        // store file name in an array
        chosenf.push(new FormControl(files[i]['name']));
    }
}
```

**Template is something like this**

```
<input id="cin" name="cin" type="file" (change)="fileChangeEvent($event)" placeholder="Upload ..." multiple/>
```

Notice **multiple** responsible for allowing multiple selections

The express API which will handle the request uses **multer** after an npm install

```
var multer = require('multer');
var path = require('path');
```

specify a static directory which will hold the files

```
// specify the folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'uploads')));
```

As specified by **multer**

**PS:** I did not investigate multer, as soon as i got it working, i moved to another task but feel free to remove unnecessary code.

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  // destination
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, './uploads/')
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.originalname);
  }
});

var upload = multer({ storage: storage });
```

And finally the endpoint

```
app.post("/api/upload", upload.array("uploads[]", 12), function (req, res) {
  console.log('files', req.files);
  res.send(req.files);
});
```